# Where can I find the text of the poem "Climbing Tintagel" by (I think) Vicki Feaver?

Tags: poetry, identification-request

I have lost one of my favourite poems, *Climbing Tintagel*, which I think is by [Vicki Feaver](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicki_Feaver). I read it in a library book that had works by three (women) poets many years ago. I can't find it online even though I remember many of the lines more-or-less accurately... something like this (line breaks omitted as I don't recall them):

> Ghosts don't exist, you said, except as legends in our head. But if they did, and we could choose a haunting place, we wouldn't moon about in graveyards, or return to clank around our enemies. We'd go back to where
>   We once were happiest, following Arthur and his queen up cliff and crag [...]

Where can I find this poem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in *The Handless Maiden* by Vicky Feaver. Published by Cape Poetry. Available on Amazon

Comment: You are right, [Google Books'](https://play.google.com/store/books/details/The_Handless_Maiden?id=xcSyNCa-Z8oC) free first page lists the poem in the book's contents.

Comment: Thanks! Do we need to advertise for Amazon here though?

Comment: @Zanna iirc links to Amazon get converted to have a referral link for SE, so links to Amazon might help SE in some small ways